# Does an antiproton have a proton number of 1 or -1

Tags: particle-physics, notation, protons

I have a disagreement with someone; they have written this equation:
$$
\,^{0}_{0}\gamma\to\,^1_1p+\,^1_1\bar p
$$

I disagree, and say that the anti-proton should have a proton number of -1, not 1. Who is correct?

Comment: Probably useful reading: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/parint.html#c2

Comment: You are, obviously. There are no known violation of baryon number conservation (some might say *unfortunately*, as we consider the amount of money we spent on tracking proton decay) at least so far as we have been able to test this so far. Hence,  since the photon obviously has baryon number 0, it follows you are right.

Comment: I'd be surprised if IUPAC or similar had issued guidelines on notation for anti-nuclides. I'm struggling to find any papers which bother to write down the atomic number, since that information is contained in the symbol for the element anyway.

Comment: can you give a link for the formula?

Comment: @annav it was in a sample paper my college put together, we had to fill in the three lower numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [baryon number,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number) and the proton has baryon number 1,  and all anti baryons have a baryon number of -1. Quarks have a baryon number of 1/3 and antiquarks -1/3.

Baryon number is conserved in the present standard model of particle physics. There are extensions that predict [decays of the proton,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay) and thus non conservation of baryon number but experiments up to now do not validated the proposals.

So you are correct but not using the correct terminology.

The equation you give cannot be  correct; a single gamma ray cannot go into two particles: the photon has no mass so there is no center of mass on the left, whereas there is on the right. If the gamma is not a gamma ray but a massive particle with mass larger than the two masses, it is OK as far as conservation laws go, although the symbolism on the left with the numbers is not clear to what quantum numbers it refers.